# Is it possible to use Metro apps in "desktop mode"?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

Some of the metro apps are pretty interesting and could spare the user to install third-party apps, like the PDF reader app, the messenger app, ...  The major issue with these apps is that it seems impossible to launch them in a windowed mode, which is not convenient for desktop users.

Does anyone know whether or not Windows features this possibility ?  If yes, how ?  Incidentally, if it doesn't, any idea why (reference to any Microsoft official statement, ui expert blogpost, ...) ?

Comment: Yes...Its possible.  Its requires third-party software and the even then the implementation is not perfect.  I won't list what third-party software support doing this, there are dozens of examples, every single one of them can be found with a little bit of research.

Comment: I was thinking about a Windows featured solution more than third party softwares.  Also, why -1 ?  It sound like a legit question.  In this case, a simple "no" (eventually "because" + source) would have been just fine.  Didn't know that SE networks turned into cheap quality "let me google that for you" ;)

Comment: There isn't a Windows feature that allows this. Microsoft has made it crystal clear a feature also will unlikely to happen based on the fact they ignored the request during the Windows 8 Beta. As for the reason you recieved a downvote, its because your expected to do some research on the subject, and asking for product suggestions isn't even on topic for Stack Exchange websites. As for a single example RetroUI allows for this functionality.  I will again warn you that the implementation is not perfect, you likely will experience applications, that simply do not support it.

Comment: This is the only tool I know which offers this: http://retroui.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

StarDock also released a tool which offers Windowed Mode. It is called **[ModernMix](http://www.stardock.com/products/modernmix)**

> ModernMix is a revolutionary new program that lets you run Windows® 8 "Modern" apps in a 
>   window on the desktop.
>
> Windows 8 Modern apps, also known as Metro or RT apps, will use the
>   full screen on your display regardless of how much of the screen they
>   really need. As a result, that weather app, mail program or stock
>   ticker is going to use the entirety of your computer display.

[image]

[image]

You can pin apps to the taskbar like normal Desktop applications.

[image]

Give it a try if it works the way you need it.

Here is also a video about it:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DMT5cn1IpSE