# Is it possible to run desktop Windows apps in Metro mode?

Tags: windows-8, modern-ui

I've got a Windows 8 tablet and I really like metro mode while using touchscreen. Is there any possibility of converting some of standard Windows apps to run in Metro sandbox?
To clarify: I think of some Steam titles like World of Goo, Fruit Ninja, Flight Control - they work in full screen mode anyway and they don't require any special permissions.

And yes, my tablet is x86, not arm architecture: ASUS Transformer Book T100.
This question is exact inverse of [Is it possible to use Metro apps in "desktop mode"?](https://superuser.com/questions/558193/is-it-possible-to-use-metro-apps-in-desktop-mode)

Comment: All the programs you mention are full Win32 applications and are NOT ran within a sandbox.  There are programs that allow you to run almost any Win32 application within a sandbox.  What you want, running a Win32 aplication within the WinRT sandbox **isn't possible**

Comment: Actually my only aim is to enable the use of metro gestures. Closing an app by sliding from top to bottom nad so on...

Comment: Those gestures do not extend to the Win32 library.

Answer (score -1):

[Based on your note](https://superuser.com/questions/695839/is-it-possible-to-run-desktop-windows-apps-in-metro-mode/947066#comment885731_695839), there is a solution. You can check several [implementations of gestures using AutoHotKey tool](https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=3hm5Vc7nMMb-ywOfh42wBg&fg=1#q=gestures+autohotkey). I haven't tried them but I have general experience with [AutoHotKey tool](http://ahkscript.org) so basically I think they should work - especially for simple tasks like closing a window. Maybe not all gesture implementations will sufficiently fit your needs, but perhaps you can find something.

The good thing is that all of these implementations should be open source so with some effort you can add feature(s) if you are badly missing something.

Comment: To downvoters: If you can figure out something better than the workaround I came with, please let me know or post an answer. The above is currently the only solution I know.